# What is the jQueryMobile default font?

Tags: jquery, fonts

Nothing more than the title already says. Can anybody tell me what the default font of jQueryMobile is? I can't seem to find it in the CSS or anywhere on Google...

Comment: is very easy to look in a browser console and inspect the css for any element, including body tag and see what font is, what file and what line it comes from

Comment: Yeah, that's how I tried to find it... It could also be it's just not set and default by browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It defaults to this....

```
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif /*{global-font-family}*/;
```

You can also set it to whatever you want by using the Theme Roller.

http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

Comment: what is it allowing to be changed to. there are so many fonts but how can i implement them into themeroller